# Ups Integration and getting Track number

Tags: c#

How can I use UPS integration in my asp.net application to get tracking information for a package?

Answer (score 3):

You will find the UPS [Integrate Tracking Tools](http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/tracking/tools/index.html) on their homepage. You can find a sample that integrates with the UPS service at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Benz_CPE.aspx)